# Add labels to bars /remove broders in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, bar-chart

I created a waterfall chart following these [instructions](https://www.stomperusa.com/2019/05/27/basic-waterfall-graphs-in-r/).

Unfortunately, so far I was not able to

1. Add labels to the bars nor
2. Remove the black border of the graph.

```r
df <- tribble(
  ~Category, ~Value, 
  # --------- header record ----------
  "Prev Budget", 5,
  "Salaries", 0.1,
  "CapEx", 0.175,
  "Travel", -0.2,
  "Contracting", -0.1,
  "Operations", -0.2,
  "RealEstate", -0.1,
  "Gap to Target", -0.175,
  "Current Budget", -4.5
)

levels <- df$Category

data1 <- df  %>%
  mutate(Category = factor(Category, levels = levels),
         ymin = round(cumsum(Value), 3),
         ymax = lag(cumsum(Value), default = 0),
         xmin = c(head(Category, -1), NA),
         xmax = c(tail(Category, -1), NA),
         Impact = ifelse(Category %in% c(as.character(df$Category[1]), 
                         as.character(df$Category[nrow(df)])),"Budget",
                         ifelse(Value > 0, "Increase", "Decrease")
         ))

g <- ggplot(data1) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "right", panel.grid = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)) +
  labs(y = "USD Millions", x = "Expense Category", 
    title = "Explanation of Budget Gap Closure")

w <- 0.4  #use to set width of bars

g <- g +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = as.integer(Category) - w/2,
                xmax = as.integer(Category) + w/2, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax,
                fill = Impact), colour = "black") +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = levels) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = (c("Decrease" = "blue", "Increase" = "orange", 
                    "Budget" = "black")))

g <- g +
  geom_segment(data = data1[1:(nrow(data1) -1), ], aes(x = xmin,
                                                     xend = xmax,
                                                     y = ymin,
                                                     yend = ymin))
g
```

I searched through forums but it seems usual solutions do not work in the waterfall chart (e.g., panel.border = element_blank()).

Answer (score 0):

To remove the panel border use `theme(panel.border = element_blank())`(Not sure why it was not working for you). To add labels to your chart you could use a `geom_text`. As you did not specify what labels you want to add to your chart and where you want to place the labels I went for the totals which I placed on top for positive values and at the bottom for negative ones:

```
library(ggplot2)

g +
  geom_text(
    aes(
      x = as.integer(Category),
      y = ymin + if_else(Value > 0, + .1, -.1),
      vjust = if_else(Value > 0, 0, 1),
      label = ymin
    )
  ) +
  theme(panel.border = element_blank())
```

[image]